# How to get rid of geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create an opening door when the user clicks on a sphere in three.js. I tried doing it with a model but I managed to get it to just appear in the correct  position rather than rota to it through animation.

I decided to try to focus on an easier scenario and just use a rectangle I would make in three.js. After hours of trying to get it to work I managed to get it to spin and stop when at 90 degrees. However it was rotating around its y axis which was found in the center of the rectangle.

I found this tutorial : https://jsfiddle.net/uxzmsLfr/1/

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh, pivot;

 init();
 animate();

 function init() {

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
camera.position.z = 1;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.2, 0.5, 0.2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set(0, -.25, 0);
scene.add( mesh );

var geo2 = geometry.clone();
geo2.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(90)); // ROTATE GEOMETRY SO IT'S IN THE CORRECT ORIENTATION

  var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geo2, material );
mesh2.position.set( 0, .25, 0 ); // MOVE THE GEOMOETRY UP BY HALF SO PIVOT IS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE GEO
mesh2.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 2);
 mesh.add(mesh2);

pivot = new THREE.Group();
pivot.position.set( 0.0, 0.25, 0 ); // MOVE THE PIVOT BACK TO WORLD ORIGN
mesh.add( pivot ); // THIS ADDS THE PIVOT TO THE CENTRE OF THE GEOMOETRY, WHICH WAS THEN ADDING MESH2 IN THE WRONG PLACE
pivot.add( mesh2 );

// VISUALISE PIVOT
var pivotSphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.01 );
var pivotSphere = new THREE.Mesh(pivotSphereGeo);
pivotSphere.position.set( 0,0,0 );
pivotSphere.position.z = 0.1;
 scene.add( pivotSphere );

scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper() );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    pivot.rotation.z += 0.01;

renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

And so far I managed to do the same with my code. The only thing that I'm struggling with now is how to remove the stationary rectangle?

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example uses the `mesh` plane to offset the position of the second mesh. You can always use a group for these purposes if you don't want to render anything.

So, replace the line:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

with:

```
mesh = new THREE.Group();
```

And rename the variable accordingly to not have a confusing code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two plane meshes in the code above. The first one is defined by:

```js
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set(0, -.25, 0);
scene.add( mesh );
```

The second one (the "door") is defined by:

```js
var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geo2, material );
mesh2.position.set( 0, .25, 0 ); // MOVE THE GEOMOETRY UP BY HALF SO PIVOT IS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE GEO
mesh2.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 2);
mesh.add(mesh2);
```

Removing the code that defines the first one will remove the non-door rectangle. But you can't simply remove that code can call it a day, because notice the last line of the `mesh2` definition:

```js
mesh.add(mesh2);
```

This means `mesh2` was added as a *child* of `mesh`. The `pivot` group is also a child of `mesh`. In both cases, replace `mesh` with `scene`, and you should be good to go.